# Is MultiByteToWideChar reentrant or threadsafe?

Tags: winapi, unicode, thread-safety

Multiple threads in my application will be calling MultiByteToWideChar for converting UTF-8 to wchar_t strings. 
I've been unable to find any documentation which states whether this function is re-entrant or  thread safe. I want to avoid synchronizing calls to this method if not needed. Does anyone know the answer or how to find it?

Comment: May I recommend boost::nowide as a better self-contained alternative for your task?

Comment: Boost is currently not an option on my project, but that does look like a better approach. Thanks.

Comment: No need for boost. Just download this header-only piece and #include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is thread safe ... but I don't have a definitive link to prove it!

There is some discussion on  [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/6398cda5-5393-4b16-b8dc-5bbf8902033f/) ... but in general the rule would be that if an API call does not have some specific context (eg. a handle) it is called with or other explicit threading rules (ie. the whole GDI layer) then it should be thread safe.

It would certainly be good to see this more explicitly called out in the documentation though.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the helpful discussion.